# Is it possible to load dynamic meta tags for client side rendered Quasar app?

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

Apologies if you find my question inappropriate. I wanted to know if there's a way to add meta tags dynamically in Quasar? I don't want to make it SSR as I want dynamic meta tags for a single route and not the rest of 10 routes.

I tried different modules, vue-head, vue-meta. It changes the title and information in the app itself, but when tested via https://metatags.io/ the meta tags don't show up. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Did you try vue-meta?

Comment: Yes, I tried vue-meta. No luck. vue-meta changes the title/meta of the app but the same content will not reflect in https://metatags.io/ because the app isn't SSR

Comment: did you find a solution for this? does the app have to be SSR ?

Comment: Yes, only SSR would help Amina.

Comment: You could get it working with vue-meta if you prerender the pages on build.